# Existing software to make iOS logs from application available remotely?

Tags: ios, logging

Is anyone familiar with a framework or library that can be added to an iOS application that captures all logs and sends them to a cloud-based service that you can then go and log into to look at?  Hoping that some company is already offering this in a SAAS model.

Our enterprise development team is considering how to make device logs (both diagnostic and crash logs) to our support department so that when a customer calls reporting a problem the support department has access to the background and context in which the problem occurred.  We will have about 5000 devices sending logs which at any point could be requested to be viewed by a support techWe'd prefer not to roll our own remote logging viewer.

For example, for some of our server-side code we use a product called Gibraltar, which takes care of sending the logs and presenting them via a software interface for support - [gibraltar](http://www.gibraltarsoftware.com)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know any frameworks for application logs, but for crash logs you can use bugsense framework http://www.bugsense.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crittercism http://crittercism.com/developers does exactly this.

They send crash reports automatically (main product)

They can also log handled exceptions (enterprise feature I guess) - Log handled exceptions can be used for diagnostic logging. (read http://support.crittercism.com/customer/portal/articles/685301-fully-utilizing-handled-exceptions).

Additionally, breadcrumbs feature will help you find out whats the path user took before he reached a crash/issue

You can also attach a username to every log/crash report which will help your support team identify the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [Bugfender](http://bugfender.com), it's a product we have built to solve this problem.

It's easy to integrate and you can choose which devices you want to get the logs from. Our service works offline and online, we have spent a lot of time to make it reliable and easy to use.

Compared to other products, you don't need any crash to get the logs, you choose when you want them.